# I need to scroll my selected list to top using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a data coming in list, I need to scroll my selected list to top using jquery.
How would I do that?

list that has class active is supposed to move to top.

My Code is like

```
<ul>
<li>test data</li>
<li>test data</li>
<li>test data</li>
<li class='active'>test data</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I have tried that

Comment: $("#licurrentSession" ).scrollTop(0);    This is what I am doing but no luck. Might be doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the easiest solution but you can use this jquery (just a quick example, you can factorize it of course):

```
var $li = $('li.active');
var $ul = $('ul');
var ulHeight = $ul.height();
var liHeight = $li.height();

$(document).on('click', '.button', function(event) {   
    $ul.scrollTop($li.position().top - liHeight);
});
```

Demo here on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lyncee/2o4sncv7/2/

Hope that can help,

L

Comment: $("#licurrentSession" + CurrentSession).addClass('active');
        var $li = $('li.active');
        var $ul = $('ul');
        var ulHeight = $ul.height();
        var liHeight = $li.height();
        $ul.scrollTop($li.position().top - liHeight);

Thanks for ur solution but it is not working for me.  One more thing I need this scroll top on page load not on click. I have used your code but no luck. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Oh okay, its on the loading on the page sorry. you can use the $(document).ready event then: Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/lyncee/w01hmb62/2/ Also, check your css to see if it matches mine, it can be the cause.

Comment: In my code there is other ul tags also. Might be that is causing the issue. I need to shift this particular ul's li